# Right settings for uwsgi.ini file with Django and pipenv

Tags: python, django, ubuntu, uwsgi, pipenv

Usually, I don't use pipen and  working with virtualenv, virtualenvwrapper and requirements.txt with my django projects. In this case my uwsgi.ini file looks like:
[uwsgi]

```
project = cv-base
uid = cvc
base = /home/%(uid)
chdir = %(base)/%(project)
home = %(base)**/Env**/%(project) <----!!!!!!!
module = %(project).wsgi:application
master = true
processes = 5
socket = /run/uwsgi/%(project).sock
chown-socket = %(uid):www-data
chmod-socket = 660
vacuum = true
```

Where values **home** have links to my virtualenv thrue folder Env. But now I cant have this folder, and cant unrestand what to substitute here.

At log file I got an error

```
 !!! Python Home is not a directory: /home/cvc/Env/cv-base !!!
Jun 26 13:48:55 CV-base uwsgi[12482]: Set PythonHome to /home/cvc/Env/cv-base
```

Comment: Well, where exactly is your project home?

Comment: @DanielRoseman My root folder from which I ran the `pipenv install `command are /home/cvc/cv-base

Comment: OK so why did you put `/Env` in the home directory setting?

Comment: I dont now right link to virtualenv using pipenv

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `pipenv --venv` for printing the virtual env directory that is `pipenv` is using.

```
$ mkdir test
$ cd test
$ pipenv shell
…
$ pipenv --venv
/home/foobar/.local/share/virtualenvs/a-atLBagCC
```

So you should use the option `virtualenv = /home/foobar/.local/share/virtualenvs/a-atLBagCC` in your `uwsgi.ini` file